# Angular Material Data Table not displaying a row

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-datatables

I am creating a sample list of data and implementing the data-table here [Material Data Table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview), The pagination I've use is having a numbers but the display rows is empty. I don't know why the rows is not displaying.

Here is my code.

**`Component.html`**

```
<div class="row mt-5 mat-elevation-z8">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
    </mat-form-field>
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
        <!-- ID Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Generated Number Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="generated_no">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Generated Number </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.generated_no}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Name Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.name}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
        </tr>
    </table>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

**`Component.ts`**

```
export class CouponComponent implements OnInit {
  coupons: Coupon[] = [];

  displayedColumns = ['id', 'generated_no', 'name'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Coupon>;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(
    private couponService: CouponService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) { 
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.coupons)
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCoupons();
  }

  getCoupons(): void {
    this.couponService.getCoupons()
    .subscribe(coupons => this.dataSource.data = coupons);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // Datasource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }
}
```

and the output is only this the pagination has a number but the table has no rows is displaying.
[image]

Did I forgot to include something??

**EDIT:**

The filter is working too, if I type something in the filter the number in pagination is changing, so it means my `dataSource` is not empty.

This is the content of HTML

[image]

**ANOTHER EDIT**

After looking to this example [Data Table](https://stackblitz.com/angular/oapjllodoqk?file=app%2Ftable-overview-example.ts) I found out that it is using a **6.0.0** dependency So I run `npm update` to my project directory to update also my dependencies, and here it looks like.

**`package.json`**

[image: package.json]

but while running the `ng serve` I encounter this error.

[image: Output]

Comment: can you try this `this.couponService.getCoupons().subscribe(coupons => this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(coupons));`

Comment: did not work, also the number in pagination is being 0.

Comment: can you create stackblitz or plunker?

Comment: delete `this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;` these statements.

Comment: Sorry I also want to share the code but I don't know how to create an app there, honestly I am new in angular and I am just using an in-app-memory-data that can be found in the site tutorial that is how I manipulate my coupon data. also I don't know why the examples in the data-table site is not also working when I am running in the stackblitz.

Comment: I'm having the same issue where my ng-containers are being commented out and seeing those bindings

Answer (score 0):

I think we should push angular change detection cycle after datasource initialize.

```
getCoupons(): void {
  this.couponService.getCoupons()
  .subscribe(coupons => {
    this.dataSource.data = coupons;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.ref.markForCheck();
  });
}
```

import ChangeDetectorRef and include it in your constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef)

Hope this will help.

Comment: import ChangeDetectorRef from where?

Comment: import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

Comment: sorry but still not working, I really don't know why is this not working.

Comment: Can you please share fiddle?

Comment: I am having exactly same scenario and its working for me

Comment: Sorry I also want to share the code but I don't know how to create an app there, honestly I am new in angular and I am just using an in-app-memory-data that can be found in the site tutorial that is how I manipulate my coupon data. also I don't know why the examples in the data-table site is not also working when I am running in the stackblitz.

Comment: Not sure this is problem however try to remove this line from constructor
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.coupons)

Comment: still not working, I updated my question regarding to the html I didn't know why the `<table>` contains a comment only?